# Retrieving MAC addresses based on PCI interface connections and SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently using this C# method to retrieve MAC addresses from a user's computer as a sort of unique identification. It retrieves the MAC address based on the fact that the physical card is connected to the PCI interface.

```
public static string returnMAC()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select MACAddress, PNPDeviceID FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE MACAddress IS NOT NULL AND PNPDEVICEID IS NOT NULL");
    ManagementObjectCollection mObject = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in mObject)
    {
        string pnp = obj["PNPDeviceID"].ToString();
        if (pnp.Contains("PCI\\"))
        {
            string mac = obj["MACAddress"].ToString();
            mac = mac.Replace(":", string.Empty);
            return mac;
        }
    }
    return "Nothing happened...";
}
```

A method I used previously was pulled straight from MSDN, but due to some issues it inherently had (like pulling the wireless' MAC instead of the LAN line), I switched it out for this one.

I have tested this method on Windows 7 and 8.1 systems, and it works fine in retrieving the physical MAC address. With that said - it uses SQL queries to search for strings, instead of a more typical method that uses `System.Net.XXX` - a more "built-in" and "native" method. Correct me if I am wrong on this.

Is there any way to make this better? I can't think of what would make it better, but on the top of my head - LINQ queries? Native methods? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string returnMAC()
```

The [C# coding conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) state that functions should be UpperCamelCase. Additionally that function name is not optimal, `returnMAC`, return it from where? More appropriate would be `GetMAC` or `RetrieveMAC`.

---

You should add [XML documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) to this method.

---

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select MACAddress, PNPDeviceID FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE MACAddress IS NOT NULL AND PNPDEVICEID IS NOT NULL");
```

This could benefit from using a [literal/verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"
SELECT
    MACAddress,
    PNPDeviceID
FROM
    Win32_NetworkAdapter
WHERE
    MACAddress IS NOT NULL AND
    PNPDEVICEID IS NOT NULL");
```

---

```
ManagementObjectCollection mObject = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in mObject)
```

Both variable names are not great. You should avoid naming something `obj` if it is not an `Object`. Also you have the variable `mObject` which is a `ManagementObjectCollection` but can easily be confused to be a `ManagementObject`. Despite not being a great alternative either, `collection` and `item` might be better...though, only slightly.

```
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject item in collection)
```

---

```
string pnp = obj["PNPDeviceID"].ToString();
```

Again, I would have rather named this variable `pnpId` or `deviceId`.

---

```
string pnp = obj["PNPDeviceID"].ToString();
if (pnp.Contains("PCI\\"))
{
    string mac = obj["MACAddress"].ToString();
    mac = mac.Replace(":", string.Empty);
    return mac;
}
```

This whole block can be shortened without losing much readability:

```
    if (item["PNPDeviceID"].ToString().Contains("PCI\\"))
    {
        return item["MACAddress"].ToString().Replace(":", string.Empty);
    }
```

Though, it seems a little bit messy at first sight, I think it's within an acceptable level.

---

```
return "Nothing happened...";
```

A more appropriate return value would be `""` or `"No PCI device found."`.

Of course, the most appropriate action would be to throw an exception, as that should not happen during normal operation.

Comment: Thanks! The naming schemes are definitely something I can work on. In regards to the actual lower-level code stuff like retrieving MAC addresses, are there better ways?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: I never had to retrieve the MAC address, so I can't really tell.